# Source file requires different compiler version (nightly builds issue) - solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, remix

```
SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.15;
^---------------------^
```

Comment: Could you explain where you get this error and what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: shashwat@ShashwatGupta:~/Music/BlockChain/ETHERUIM/simple-storage-truffle$  truffle version
Truffle v4.1.3 (core: 4.1.3)
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)

Comment: i am facing error while i am deploying contact with truffle

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are using some functions that not working on greater versions. 
Try to set 
pragram solidity ^0.4.15; 
if the problem still there, paste here your contract.

Comment: here is the code https://hastebin.com/oroteyejer.cs

Comment: @ngCourse Ivan is correct. Using `0.4.15` without the `^` means you are specifying exactly which compiler you are using. If you do `^0.4.15`, it represents that version and above.

Comment: i did mention on ^0.4.15 ... it still have that same error

Comment: I try in https://remix.ethereum.org/ your code and when i change pragma to ^0.4.15 the error disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a Remix environment just go to settings and change the compiler version.

[image: remix settings]